# How to manage concurrence reading from a file descripter using multiple boost::thread objests. (boost threads management)

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, boost

I am writing an application for a bar-code reader and I have several methods to execute synchronously. As an initial point I am going to read data from the device concurrently. Below is my scenario.

Environment 
OS: CENTOS 6.3 (LINUX)
Boost: 1.41

1. Always waiting for decoded data (bar-code scanned data) from device
2. Send Acknowledgement for received decoded data
3. Meanwhile send requests to device
4. and get response or acknowledgement from the device

for data reading purpose I have 2 methods and I have 1 method to send commands to the decoder. I am trying with boost::thread examples from internet and still I couldn't get a good idea to handle the scenario. Below is a sample codes from my application. Please advise me for thread management in situations like this.

I am using OOP approach below are the methods from DeviceRS232.cpp class

```
// Open and set attributes for serial port
int DeviceRS232::openSerialPort()
{
    int fd, baudr, status, portStatus;
    setDefaultAttributes();

    switch(getBaudRate())
    {
        case      50 : baudr = B50;
                       break;
        case      75 : baudr = B75;
                       break;
        case     110 : baudr = B110;
                       break;
        case     134 : baudr = B134;
                       break;
        case     150 : baudr = B150;
                       break;
        case     200 : baudr = B200;
                       break;
        case     300 : baudr = B300;
                       break;
        case     600 : baudr = B600;
                       break;
        case    1200 : baudr = B1200;
                       break;
        case    1800 : baudr = B1800;
                       break;
        case    2400 : baudr = B2400;
                       break;
        case    4800 : baudr = B4800;
                       break;
        case    9600 : baudr = B9600;
                       break;
        case   19200 : baudr = B19200;
                       break;
        case   38400 : baudr = B38400;
                       break;
        case   57600 : baudr = B57600;
                       break;
        case  115200 : baudr = B115200;
                       break;
        case  230400 : baudr = B230400;
                       break;
        case  460800 : baudr = B460800;
                       break;
        case  500000 : baudr = B500000;
                       break;
        case  576000 : baudr = B576000;
                       break;
        case  921600 : baudr = B921600;
                       break;
        case 1000000 : baudr = B1000000;
                       break;
        default      : printf("invalid baudrate\n");
                       return(1);
                       break;
    }

    //  Open serial port
    fd = open(getSerialPort().c_str(),  O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    if(fd == -1)
    {
        printf("Unable to open serial port...\n");
        perror(getSerialPort().c_str());
        return 1;
    }

    fdRS232 = fd;

    fcntl(fdRS232, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
    status = tcgetattr(fdRS232, &oldSerialPortSetting);
    if(status == -1)
    {
        close(fdRS232);
        printf("Unable to get serial port attributes...\n");
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&newSerialPortSetting, 0, sizeof(newSerialPortSetting));
    newSerialPortSetting.c_cflag = baudr | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD | CRTSCTS; // | CRTSCTS
    newSerialPortSetting.c_iflag = IGNPAR;
    newSerialPortSetting.c_oflag = 0;
    newSerialPortSetting.c_lflag = 0;
    newSerialPortSetting.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    newSerialPortSetting.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

    ChangeCTS(fdRS232, 0);
    ChangeRTS(fdRS232, 0);


  return 0;
}


// send data to the decoder
    int DeviceRS232::sendDataBuffer(const unsigned char *dataBuffer, size_t bufferSize)
    {
        int sentSize;

        ChangeRTS(fdRS232, 1);
        ChangeCTS(fdRS232, 1);

        while(true)
        {
            sentSize = write(fdRS232, dataBuffer, bufferSize);
            if(sentSize > 0)
                break;
        }

        hasCommandSent = true;
        sleep(1);

        return sentSize;
    }

// Receive response from the decoder    
    int DeviceRS232::receiveDataBuffer(unsigned char *dataBuffer, size_t bufferSize)
    {
        unsigned char recvBuffer[251];
        unsigned char *ptrChar;
        int nBytes, portStatus;
        int inputBufSize = 0;

        ChangeCTS(fdRS232, 0);
        ChangeRTS(fdRS232, 0);

        while(inputBufSize <= 0)
        {
            ioctl(fdRS232, FIONREAD, &inputBufSize);
            usleep(1);
        }

        //TEST PURPOSES
        //sleep(1);


        if(inputBufSize > 0)
        {
            memset(recvBuffer, 0x00, sizeof(recvBuffer));
            nBytes = read(fdRS232, recvBuffer, 251);
            if(nBytes < 0)
            {
                printf("Unable to receive data...\n");
                perror("/dev/ttyS0");
            }

            std::cout << "RECV Length: " << nBytes << std::endl;
            for(int i=0; i<nBytes; i++)
            {
                std::cout << "recvBuffer[" << (int)i << "]: ";
                printf("%x\n", recvBuffer[i]);
            }
            std::cout << "-----------------------------------" << std::endl;

            //ChangeRTS(fdRS232, 1);
            //sleep(1);
        }

        strcpy((char *)dataBuffer, (char *)recvBuffer);
        inputBufSize = 0;

        return nBytes;

    }

// Receive decoded data from decoder.    
    int DeviceRS232::receiveDecodedData(unsigned char *dataBuffer, size_t bufferSize)
    {
        unsigned char recvBuffer[251];
        unsigned char *ptrChar;
        int nBytes, portStatus;
        int inputBufSize = 0;

        ChangeCTS(fdRS232, 0);
        ChangeRTS(fdRS232, 0);

        while(inputBufSize <= 0)
        {
            ioctl(fdRS232, FIONREAD, &inputBufSize);
            usleep(1);
        }

        //  TEST PURPOSES
        //sleep(1);



        if(inputBufSize > 0)
        {
            int decodePacketLen;
            //unsigned char
            memset(recvBuffer, 0x00, sizeof(recvBuffer));
            nBytes = 0;

            while(nBytes < ((int)recvBuffer[0] + 2))
            {
                int index = 0;
                if(nBytes != 0)
                    index = nBytes - 1;

                nBytes += read(fdRS232, &recvBuffer[index], 251);
                if(nBytes == ((int)recvBuffer[0] + 2))
                    break;
            }

            std::cout << "RECV Length: " << (int)recvBuffer[0] << std::endl;
            for(int i=0; i<nBytes; i++)
            {
                std::cout << "recvBuffer[" << (int)i << "]: ";
                printf("%x\n", recvBuffer[i]);
            }
            std::cout << "-----------------------------------" << std::endl;

            //ChangeRTS(fdRS232, 1);
            //ChangeCTS(fdRS232, 1);
            //sleep(1);
        }

        //strcpy((char *)dataBuffer, (char *)recvBuffer);
        memcpy((char *)dataBuffer, recvBuffer, sizeof(recvBuffer)/sizeof(recvBuffer[0]));
        inputBufSize = 0;

        return nBytes;

    }

// Method I am going to use for concurrent reading

void DeviceRS232::startReadTread()
{
    boost::thread *dataReader1, *dataReader2;
    dataReader1 = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&DeviceRS232::decodedDataReadThread, this));

    dataReader2 = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&DeviceRS232::commandResponseReadThread, this));
    dataReader2->join();
}


// Finally I am hoping to create and call to thread handling method from main method.
int main()
{
    DeviceRS232 dev_rs232;
    dev_rs232.setDefaultAttributes();
    dev_rs232.openSerialPort();

    dev_rs232.startReadTread();

    return 0;
}
```

I can upload the complete program for further reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can more easily achieve what John Zwinck mentions by using Boost Asio's serial communications options.

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/serial_ports.html

This has the magic benefit of making your code portable

> *Serial ports are available on all POSIX platforms. For Windows, serial ports are only available at compile time when the I/O completion port backend is used (which is the default). A program may test for the macro BOOST_ASIO_HAS_SERIAL_PORT to determine whether they are supported.*

Comment: This is a good suggestion.  I don't think the code in question is going to be portable anyway (there was a mention of plug-and-play detection), but since Boost is already in use then ASIO is definitely worth a look for the event loop.

Comment: Thanks for the new suggestion, I feel this is a easier way to handle this level problems, Is this feature is available with Boost version 1.41 ?

Comment: @DigTheCode yes: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/serial_ports.html

Answer (score 0):

Rather than spin-waiting in a separate thread to read data, you should use an event-based solution like select(), epoll(), WaitForMultipleEvents, etc.  That way you can avoid wasting a CPU core for reading, and avoid mutexes, and get woken up exactly when data is available to read.

Comment: Thanks for the steps, will this be working when increasing the number of devices connected to the PC ? And additionally I have add several other events also (like Plug and Play events for devise connection/removal events)

Comment: It will work, yes.  If you have many devices you will be better off using a platform-specific API like epoll() on Linux or WaitForMultipleEvents on Windows, rather than select() which does not scale quite as well, but even select() will work fine for a few dozen devices.  And if you have extra work that needs to be done which cannot wait on a file descriptor, just use a timeout when you wait for data, and if the wait times out, do your extra work and then wait again.  A suitable timeout value might be a few milliseconds or so, depending on how responsive your extra work must be.

Comment: I am trying to handle this using epoll() I already read some articles and sample source code about how to use epoll() but I cannot understand the way it can handle multiple events on the same file descriptor. I found tutorials to handle using multiple file descriptors. Currently data reading can be done using a usleep(100000)